# How do I create a desktop shortcut for VNC?

Tags: remote-desktop, shortcut, alias, apple-remote-desktop

I connect to my Raspberry Pi with VNC from my MacBook, however to do that every time I have to open the Finder, then select Go from the menu, then Connect to server. I am looking forward for having a shortcut (or an alias) on the desktop so I have to take minimal steps.

This is the address I use for VNC connection: `vnc://raspberrypi.local:5901`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open a VNC session to your Raspberry Pi (e.g. Safari or run `open vnc://<host>:<port>`).
2. Grab the small icon to the left of the host name with your pointer
3. Drag and drop the icon to the desktop

It will create a `.vncloc` shortcut, which then you can double-click to open the connection.

[image]